# Get list of all google groups within the orgranization

Tags: google-app-maker

I am looking to get the list of all google groups within my organization. I used the var groups = GroupsApp.getGroups();  this gives me only the list of groups that I am a member of.

What is the best way of getting the list of all groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list all groups with Admin SDK Directory Service:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#list_all_groups

Comment: Thank you very much